# Events in AutoMapper when mapping an item

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have setup mappings for a number of classes, however in some scenarios I will want to apply some custom mapping or apply values to additional properties that won't be mapped, the reason I can't do this custom mapping centrally is because it is context-sensitive so the variables/properties won't be available.

Is there an event I can bind to within AutoMapper so that I can populate certain properties after Mapper.Map has been called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create mapping like below:

```
Action<object,object> beforeMap = (src, dst) => { Console.WriteLint("BeforeMap"); };
Mapper.CreateMap<Src, Dst>().BeforeMap((src, dst) =>
    {
                  if(beforeMap!=null)
                       beforeMap(src,dst);
    });

Mapper.Map(new Src(), new Dst()); // - output: BeforeMap
```

And set new beforeMap whenever you need context-sensitive BeforeMap handler. if you don't need additional action, just set beforeMap to null.

```
beforeMap = (src, dst) => { Console.WriteLint("NEW BeforeMap") };

Mapper.Map(new Src(), new Dst()); // - output: NEW BeforeMap
```

The same you can do with AfterMap.